# How to display an i18n message with thymleaf

Tags: internationalization, thymeleaf, jhipster

**1st question :**

I generated a Jhipster application with the npm module (jhipster-generator).
The application run well.
I took a template file at random : for example settings.html
A part of the content is :

```
<h2>User settings for [<b>{{settingsAccount.login}}</b>]</h2>
```

I wish to replace it with a thymleaf i18n message like :

```
<h2 th:text="#{user.settings.for}">[<b>{{settingsAccount.login}}</b>]</h2>
```

So I added the key into both  "messages_en" (and "messages_fr" I created) files ; located at src\main\resources\i18n\messages_xx.properties

So why, at displaying the settings page, the text is not displayed ? But only the angularjs variable is displayed :

```
<h2> [<b>{{settingsAccount.login}}</b>]</h2>
```

I tried to declare the th tag at index.html :

```
<html class="no-js" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

but nothing happens.

**2nd (subsidiary) question :**

In addition, I noticed in the generated code that ThymleafConfiguration for spring boot specify a classpath resource bundle as :

```
messageSource.setBasename("classpath:/mails/messages/messages");
```

This classpath doesn't exist, but it is :

```
messageSource.setBasename("classpath:/mails/i18n/messages");
```

Despite of this mistake, It works anyway, I don't know why...

Thanks.

EDIT : I read the jhipster documentation for i18n at http://jhipster.github.io/installing-new-languages/ but thymleaf appears to be an alternative : for example mail creation exemple is based on thymleaf for i18n.

Answer (score 0):

OK, angular-translate has to be installed at application generation for i18n.
I forgot thymeleaf, despite of I don't care i18n : I have only one language support that is not english.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this as well

Add message key with argument in property file like

```
user.settings.for=user.settings.for(0)
```

and use message key as below

```
<h2 th:text="#{user.settings.for({settingsAccount.login})}"></h2>
```